# SQL query report builder 3.0 table join problems with duplicates

Tags: join, sql-server-2008-r2, duplicates, reportbuilder3.0

I am having problems joining three tables in report builder 3.0. I have experimented with various joins and can not achieve the desired result.

PLACES
place ref, 
address,
place type     (place type = 1)

JOBS
place ref,
description,
cost,
job number,

JOBS INFO
job number,
date comp   (date comp = 25/12/2015)

I need all places with place type 1. 
Then I need to link all jobs completed 25/12/2015 by job number and then link these to places on place ref.

The first problem I have is despite which join I chose to link places to jobs and jobs info all I get is the places which have had jobs. I need to also show the places that haven't.

Also the database sometimes contains duplicate jobs so I only need to display the same job number once.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a LEFT JOIN when PLACES is your master table :

```
SELECT * FROM PLACES p
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select distinct * from Jobs j
                 INNER JOIN Jobs_Info ji ON(j.job_number = ji.job_number)
                 WHERE ji.date_comp = '25/12/2015') t
    ON(p.place_ref = t.place_ref)
WHERE p.place_type = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That has solved 1 of my problems. Now just left with the duplicate jobs. Any ideas?